# For loop is running too quickly in my discord.py bot

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a for loop that runs through a list of questions creating an embed for each question. It is meant to then wait for an answer and then ask the next question. I then upload the answers to a mongodb database (after running some checks to ensure they are valid answers.

The issue I am having is that sometimes (3 in 10 tries) it will ask two questions directly after one another without giving any time to respond to the first. I have played around with sleep() but found it still happens.

Would appreciate any help you can offer!

```
import re
import datetime
from copy import deepcopy
import emojis
import asyncio
import discord
import math
import random
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from utils.util import GetMessage
from time import sleep

"""
product = ['Name': 'Example_Name', 'Description': 'Example Description', 'Quantity in stock': 10, 'Price': 400]
Name =product[0]
Description = product[1]
Quantity = product[2]
Price= product[3]
"""





class Shop(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__} Cog has been loaded\n-----")


    @commands.command(
        name='ShopAddProduct',
        #aliases=['w'],
        description="List all the Shops",
        #usage = "[User] <Name>"
    )
    @commands.has_role("Server Player")
    @commands.has_permissions(send_messages=True)
    async def ShopAddProduct(self, ctx):
        member = ctx.author
        channel = await member.create_dm()

        await channel.send("Lets add a product. Answer the following questions to add a product to your shop")

        questionList = [
            ["What is your shop called?","Enter the Name of your shop"],
            ["What is the product called?","Enter what your product is called"],
            ["Describe your product","Enter a description"],
            ["How many of them do you have ready to sell?","Enter how many you have in stock"],
            ["how much are you selling them for?","Enter how many credits you want for this product."]

        ]
        answers = {}

        for i, question in enumerate(questionList):
                #answer = await GetMessage(self.bot, ctx, question[0], question[1])
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title=f"{question[0]}",
                    description =f"{question[1]}",
                )
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
                sent = await channel.send(embed=embed)
                try:
                    answer = await self.bot.wait_for(
                        "message",
                        timeout=60,
                        check=lambda message: isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel)
                    )

                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    await sent.delete()
                    await channel.send("Cancelling due to timeout.", delete_after=10)
                sleep(2)
                answers[i] = answer.content






        embed = discord.Embed(name="Add Product")
        for key, value in answers.items():
            embed.add_field(name=f"Question: `{questionList[key][0]}`", value=f"Answer: `{value}`", inline=False)

        m = await channel.send("Are these all valid?", embed=embed)
        await m.add_reaction("✅")
        await m.add_reaction("")

        try:
            reaction, member = await self.bot.wait_for(
                "reaction_add",
                timeout=60,
                check=lambda reaction, user: user == ctx.author
                and reaction.message.channel == channel
            )
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send("Confirmation Failure. Please try again.")
            return

        if str(reaction.emoji) not in ["✅", ""] or str(reaction.emoji) == "":
            await channel.send("Cancelling Product Addition!")

        #check answers validity
        check = await self.bot.shop.find_by_id(answers[0])
        if check == None:
            await channel.send(f"The shop `{answers[0]}` does not exist! Please try again.")
            return
        if not answers[3].isdigit():
            #not isinstance(answers[3],int):
            await channel.send(f"The quantity you submitted (`{answers[3]}`) must be whole number (integer)! Please try again.")
            return
        if not answers[4].isdigit():
            #not isinstance(answers[4],int):
            await channel.send(f"The price you submitted (`{answers[4]}`) must be whole number (integer)! Please try again.")
            return
        shopcheck = await self.bot.shopCatalogue.find_by_id(answers[0])
        productlist = shopcheck['Products']
        print(productlist)
        product = [answers[1], answers[2], int(answers[3]), int(answers[4])]
        productlist.append(product)
        print(product)
        print(productlist)
        data = {
            '_id': shopcheck['_id'],
            'Products': productlist

        }
        guild=ctx.guild
        await self.bot.shopCatalogue.upsert(data)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title=f"Product Added to Shop Catalogue!",
            #description =,
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name=f"Product:",
            value=answers[1],
            inline=True
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name=f"Description:",
            value=answers[2],
            inline=True
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name=f"Quantity:",
            value=answers[3],
            inline=False
        )
        embed.add_field(
            name=f"Price:",
            value=answers[4],
            inline=True
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
        sent = await channel.send(embed=embed)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Shop(bot))
```

Comment: Is the issue that a timeout will just continue the loop, thus sending the next message even without a reply?

Comment: I am not sure. I have found that it happens whether I timeout on the previous attempt to run it or not. It just happened after one run through that worked perefctly the next two the first three questions were asked at the same time

Comment: Another thought - the `wait_for` doesn't specify that the message must be from a certain channel (as one of the examples in the `wait_for` documentation does). If someone else sends a message in a different DM channel then it would continue the loop in whichever channel the bot is actually sending to.

Comment: Ahh, I am the only person with access to the bot currently so wouldn't be causing this issue but that is something I will need to fix before making this bot public. How would I specify which channel the message must come from may I ask? could you point me in the direction of the example you mentioned?

Comment: That's in the `wait_for` documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for). They have a couple of example, but the first one has a `check` argument that checks the channel the message was received on.

Comment: One final thought - if your bot inherits from `discord.Client` then it will see its own messages, but that would cause this issue to happen constantly (assuming `wait_for` and `on_message` trigger on the same things, I've only used the latter). I assume you're inheriting from `Bot` instead, which doesn't have that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this error before, it's happens when the bots message sends fast enough to pass the check, easy fix just make sure that only you can answer to the messages

```py
# add this
def check(message):
    channel_id = message.channel.id
    author_id = message.author.id
    return channel_id == ctx.channel.id and author_id == ctx.author.id

# change this
reaction, member = await self.bot.wait_for(
    "reaction_add",
    timeout=60,
    check=check
)
```